# ProgressDialog as drawable ? GIF or something?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, gif, progressdialog, android-drawable

I'm making a sign up activity, where i use drawables resources to interact. TextWatcher and some coding, then (example):

```
etPass.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon_lock_open, 0, R.drawable.icon_close, 0);
```

Now, i made a task to check e-mail on database. I would like to show a ProgressDialog while this task gets the result. I tried with a gif, but it doesn't animate properly. I want something like:

[image]

**Note**: I would like to do this through "setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds", once it already comes formatted and fit on the field. But i'm open to other ways.

Thanks !

Comment: try something like [this](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable/progress_medium.xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

Create a custom XML for the `EditText` with `ProgressBar`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:singleLine="true" />
    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/edit"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/edit"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/edit"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, include it in the activity

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/field1"
        layout="@layout/progress_edittext"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and then retrieve it in `onCreate()`

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private View field1;
    private EditText edit;
    private ProgressBar progress;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        field1 = findViewById(R.id.field1);
        edit = (EditText) field1.findViewById(R.id.edit);
        progress = (ProgressBar) field1.findViewById(R.id.progress);
        edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // YOUR LOGIC GOES HERE
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Works ! Thank you ! **Note**: i didn't need to
`field1 = findViewById(R.id.field1);
        edit = (EditText) field1.findViewById(R.id.edit);
        progress = (ProgressBar) field1.findViewById(R.id.progress);`
Only need: 
`ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_email);
                    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: @VictorMilazzo but you would if you had multiple `<include>`, right? :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to get a GIF and split it into frames, the [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) class will serve your needs.

Comment: Tried, but didnt work.. I think it's because setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds needs a drawable as parameter. Thanks anyway !

Comment: AnimationDrawable is a type of Drawable!

Never mind, the other answer got you what you needed

Comment: You right ! But that method doesn't accept AnimationDrawable as param :/